# PySpark / Count the number of occurrences and create a new column with UDF

Tags: pyspark, split, count, user-defined-functions, assert

I have a dataframe with several columns, including `video_id` and `tags`.

I need to create a new column in my df called `occurrencias_music` with the number of occurrences of the string "music" as a substring of any of the tags. It's not necessary that the tag is exactly the same as "music" but that it contains it as a substring.

Later, the idea is to implement a **UDF** `subtag_music_UDF` that returns *IntegerType()* and that wraps the conventional python function `subcadena_en_vector(tags)`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

subtag_music_UDF = F.udf(subcadena_en_vector, T.IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn("ocurrencias_music", subtag_music_UDF(F.col("tags")))
```

To do so, I need a function called `subcadena_en_vector(tags)`, which should receive as an argument a list of strings, and check how many elements of the vector contain as substring the word "music". And I have to test its operation with this list:

```
["a life in music", "music for life", "bso", "hans zimmer"]
```

being the result 2.

I have an idea of what the `subcadena_en_vector(tags)` function could be:

```
def subcadena_en_vector(tags, strToSearch):
    nTimes = 0
    for item in tags:
        #print(item.split())
        for subitem in item.split():
            if subitem==strToSearch:
                nTimes += 1

    return nTimes

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tags = ["a life in music", "music for life", "bso", "hans zimmer"]
  palabra = 'music'
  print(cuenta(tags,palabra)
```

The problem with this function is that later, in a correction section in which this assert is included:

```
assert(subcadena_en_vector(["a life in music", "music for life", "bso", "hans zimmer"]) == 2)
```

I get the following error:

```
> TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-3-7a51ae031d9e> in <module>()
> ----> 1 assert(subcadena_en_vector(["a life in music", "music for life", "bso", "hans zimmer"]) == 2) TypeError: subcadena_en_vector()
> takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Any ideas on how I can simplify the function so that it does the counting of occurrences and does not get that error of arguments?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: You need a string to match, why you are not passing th string while assert op?

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved the question by doing this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import Window

subtag_music = ["a life in music", "music for life", "bso", "hans zimmer"]

def subcadena_en_vector(tags):
    return(sum([1 for c in tags if "music" in c]))

print(subcadena_en_vector(subtag_music))

subtag_music_UDF = F.udf(subcadena_en_vector, T.IntegerType())
videosOcurrenciasMusicDF = videosDiasViralDF.withColumn("ocurrencias_music", subtag_music_UDF(F.col("tags")))
```

Thanks!